# How to make QTabWidget without pages

Tags: qt, tabs, qt4, hide, qtabwidget

I with to use the tabs of QTabWidget but I don't need the pages as containers.
I need only the tabs.

Is there a way I can hide or disable the page containers and display only the tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use QTabBar which includes only tabs.

Comment: Here is how I did it according to your suggestion

    QTabBar *bar = new QTabBar();
    bar->addTab("Deck 1");
    bar->addTab("Deck 2");
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(bar);